# How to rename Whatsapp contact info?

Tags: apps

Is it possible to rename whatsapp contact info? Suppose in my address book, person name is X,now the same name is coming in whatsapp, I want to rename as Y in whatsapp only.

Comment: Whatsapp reads from the contacts in Windows Phones People Hub. If you want a name to appear in a certain way in Whatsapp, it needs to be the same in the People hub.

Comment: Hopefully it can't be done, the whatsapp shows the info which is saved in phone contact it can not be changed only in whatsapp.

Comment: Sorry you cant able do like that in any of the mobiles..Even in Android or iPhone.  The name you have saved in your contact will be the same shown up in whatspp..

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, in any version of WhatsApp, not just the WP one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to People -> Select contact to change -> Edit and change name . Same name will reflect onto whatsapp contact name.

Comment: doesn't work, those options don't exist